# Understanding the ports in lauchsettings.json

Tags: visual-studio, port, visual-studio-2022, dotnet-cli

### Background

I have the following `launchsettings.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:54732",
      "sslPort": 44382
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "NoteKeeperService": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7249;http://localhost:5249",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This was generated by Visual Studio and I am trying to understand the different ports that it generated.  Specifically there are 4 different ports generated by Visual Studio:

The four ports are:

- iisSettings->iisExpress->applicationUrl (Line 7)

  - Port: 54732 - (http)
- iiSettings->IssExpress->sslPort (Line 8)

  - Port: 44382 - (https)
- profiles->applicationUrl (Line 17)

  - Port: 7249 - (https)
  - Port: 5249 - (http)

There are a pair (http and https) for IIS Express and a pair for the service directly (when it runs inside of Visual Studio, I think...?)  I am guessing they all different so you don't get any port conflicts when running in IIS Express and locally.

### Question

**And what range rules do these ports follow for generation?**

### Details (ignorable)

I am creating my own template, and I want to make sure I understand the ranges for each port number so I don't put the ports in an invalid range.  The `dotnet` templating system has a generator for ports, but it requires that I supply a range value for the ports.  I am unsure what those ranges should be, or if it even matters.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually more of an OS/Infrastructure question than a Visual Studio question, since ports are how the system will manage communications.

Generally speaking ports < 1024 may be "reserved" for use by "well known" programs. e.g. 80 for http, 443 for https, 21 for ftp etc.
The [IANA port list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) may give you a more complete picture

Safe to say for your Visual Studio template any port between 1025 and 65000 should suffice. It should be up to the end user (developer in this case) to determine if the high range port is already in use by another development project.